# CSS / margin above first paragraph

Tags: css

http://www.ratest6.com/

In the right hand sidebar under "What People Are Saying" - the title of the 'testimonial' (which says "Maggie...") and the first paragraph. I want to remove the space between the title of the individual testimonial and the first paragraph (so it looks more like a BR).

I can't find, or get rid of, the space between the h4 and the first paragraph.

The only thing I see;
1. A general P styling (margin bottom 18px)
2. A 'user agent' styling that has

`p {
    -webkit-margin-before: 1em;
    -webkit-margin-after: 1em;}`

So I wrote this (and it does nothing);

`div.textwidget p:first-child {margin: 0 0 18px 0; padding:0; -webkit-margin-before: 0;}`

Comment: decrease the 18px vlue in the margin. you will get the desired result.

Comment: Also, while not required to use SO, most users are more inclined to spend time providing a quality answer when you have a high accept %.  I would suggest going through and seeing if anyone correctly answered your question on the questions you've asked in the past.  This helps the people that helped you and it makes people more likely to invest some time in answering your questions.  If it's anything more then quick answer I won't spend any time trying to help on lost accept % question askers.

Answer (score 2):

Your style rule doesn't get applied because your `p` is not the first child but instead `h4`. You could use

```
div.textwidget h4 + p {
margin: 0 0 18px 0;
}
```

The `-webkit-` prefixed properties are not needed.

Comment: Close - the rule is actually being applied to the `first-child` of the `p` block, which doesn't actually exist.

Comment: @Hannele No, [look at the spec:](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#first-child) `p:first-child` does *not* select the first child of the `p`, but every `p` block that is the first child of his parent! If you would want the first child of the `p` block (which indeed does not exist) you would have to write `p > :first-child`!

Comment: @matthias.p My bad, that is indeed as what is written in the spec. Thanks for clarifying!

Answer (score 0):

Have you used Google's inspect tool before? You can right click on the element you want to see the styling for, and then select inspect element. This will bring up a box at the bottom which shows you the structure of the document, along with the way each element is styled.

Using this tool, I can see that your h4 tag is being styled like this:

```
h4.widget-title {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

I was able to alter the space between the `<h4>` and the `<p>` by using a negative margin, like this:

```
h4.widget-title {
    margin-bottom:-10px;
    padding:0;
}
```

Just something to try, as it may solve your issue.

Comment: Justin - yes I use both the Chrome inspector and Firebug.

Answer (score -1):

decrease the 18px vlue in the margin. you will get the desired result. Better make it zero

```
margin:0;
```

Comment: No, the 18px are below the paragraph!